# Dynamic allocating an array  (dynamic size of the vector implementation)

Tags: objective-c, c, dynamic, vector, size

In the obj-c, we can create vector objects as follows:

```
SomeClass* example[100];
```

or

```
int count[7000];
```

But what if we know the size of the vector only at the time init the class?
(Maybe we need example[756] or count[15])

Comment: C++ or Objective-C? Pick one, not both.

Comment: @sinba - `SomeClass* example[100];` doesn't create you a vector of objects. It just allocate an array that can hold pointers (100) to `SomeClass`. To create an object you should use **new** or **alloc/init**.

Comment: Why'd Rudy replace [C++] tag with [C]?  Did he see something I missed from the question?

Comment: Talk about a question with an identity crisis! It's tagged Obj-C and C but most of the answers are in C++.

Comment: I changed it from C to C++ because he's using the word `vector` and because he has the word `SomeClass` in his example. Whether these are both coincidences I don't know, but I think C++ is the best guess right now.

Comment: I replaced it because the question is about Objective-C, which is (allegedly) a superset of C, but certainly not of C++, and doesn't know anything about `std::vector<>` or similar types. IOW, ISTM that he wrongly tagged the question. His use of the word *vector* is also misleading, as he clearly means arrays. Perhaps I'm wrong, but I am not yet convinced of that. FWIW, @Seth, in Objective-C, there are Obj-C classes, so that explains the use of the name `SomeClass`. They are not the same as C++ classes.

Comment: @Rudy ok, go ahead and change it back to C or Objective C if you think it fits better since I know nothing about Objective C except that the syntax looks wretched :)

Comment: @Seth: LOL! I actually like the syntax (it comes from Smalltalk and I always liked that way to denote parameters). I guess I'll wait until Sinba comments. There are too many C++ answers to just change it now, IMO.

Comment: This question is barely answerable in its current form, due to misuse of tags and syntax by the original OP.

Comment: Thank you very much for responses, guys. Tagged [obj-c], cause us this lang. C++ - had some knowledge about std::vector<>, but didn't know how allocate dynamic count of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, those aren't vector objects, they're compile-time arrays. One of the features of compile time arrays is automatic memory management; that is, you don't have to worry about allocation and deallocation of these arrays.

If you want to create an array whose size you don't know until runtime, you'll need to use `new[]` and `delete[]`:

```
int size = somenumber;
int* arr = new int[size];

// use arr
arr[0] = 4;

// print the first value of arr which is 4
cout << arr[0];
```

The catch is that after you're done with this array, you have to deallocate it:

```
delete[] arr;
```

If you *forget* to deallocate something created by `new` with a corresponding `delete`<sup>1</sup>, you'll create a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

You are probably better off using `std::vector` though because it manages memory for you automatically:

```
// include the header
#include <vector>

using namespace std; // so we don't have std:: everywhere

vector<int> vec; // create a vector for ints
vec.push_back(4); // add some data
vec.push_back(5);
vec.push_back(6);

// vec now holds 4, 5, and 6

cout << vec[0]; // print the first element of vec which is 4

// we can add as many elements to vec as we want without having to use any
// deallocation functions on it like delete[] or anything
// when vec goes out of scope, it will clean up after itself and you won't have any leaks
```

<sup>1</sup> Make sure you use `delete` on pointers that you created with `new` and `delete[]` on pointers you make with `new[x]`. **Do not mix and match them**. Again, if you use `std::vector`, you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: Thank you, Seth Carnegie. "std::vector" is the best choice

Comment: Seth, I checked it. For voting, need 15 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use an std::vector

```
//file.mm
#include <vector>
-(void)function
{
std::vector<int> count;
std::vector<SomeClass*> example;
count.push_back(10); // add 10 to the array;
count.resize(20); // make count hold 20 objects
count[10] = 5; //set object at index of 10 to the value of 5
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you do something like:

```
SomeClass **example = calloc(numClasses, sizeof(SomeClass *));
```

or:

```
int *count = malloc(num_of_counts * sizeof(int));
```

Note that you should:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: Did you decide to modify the tag from C++ to C because you wanted to answer in C?

Comment: No, just because Objective-C (the language he mentions) is not C++, but it is a superset of C. ISTM that he chose the wrong tag.

Answer (score 1):

C++ cannot make global/local arrays of a variable size, only dynamic arrays on the heap.

```
int main() {
    int variable = 100;
    SomeClass* example = new SomeClass[variable];
    //do stuff 
    delete [] example;  //DO NOT FORGET THIS.  Better yet, use a std::vector
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know anything about objective-C, but your question is probably only one or the other.

Comment: Or `std::vector<SomeClass> my_vector(variable);` so we forget memory management altogether. :)

Comment: That explains why I couldn't remember a smart pointer for arrays.  Although how I forgot vectors is beyond me.  Must be dinner time.

Comment: Thanks, Mooing Duck! I didn't know this.